# Excel VBA to copy rows with a specific criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet in the below format. I would like to search for the project code and copy all the rows into a new sheet until the next project code. Can anyone please help how this can be done in VBA
[image]

Comment: if you search for "[vba] copy cells criteria" within Stackoverflow you will find tons of answers.